# flutter error : Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'toMap'. Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:9 Tried calling: toMap()

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, mobile

when i try to update order status from admin dashboard  this error occured although that the add function send successfully to firebase and this is my model for Order and i do this list cardItemList like that because when i get orders from firebase error occured tell me that the List not a sub typy of List,
i send the cart list of type List to  List cardItemList and that make the function add & get doing successfully but update function do that error and i don't know why and what is different of add and update i send static list to two function nothing change except status

```
class NewOrderModel
{
  String? orderId;
  String? userName;
  double? totalPrice;
  double? shipping;
  double? total;
  String? phone;
  String? address;
  String? dateTime;
  String? productName;
  String? status;
  int? quantity;
  List<dynamic>? cardItemList;
  NewOrderModel({
    this.orderId,
    this.userName,
    this.totalPrice,
    this.shipping,
    this.total,
    this.address,
    this.phone,
    this.dateTime,
    this.cardItemList,
    this.quantity,
    this.productName,
    this.status,
  });

  NewOrderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>? json)
  {
    orderId = json!['orderId'];
    userName = json['userName'];
    totalPrice = json['totalPrice'];
    shipping = json['shipping'];
    total = json['total'];
    phone=json['phone'];
    address=json['address'];
    dateTime=json['dateTime'];
    cardItemList=json['cardItemList'];
    quantity=json['quantity'];
    productName=json['productName'];
    status=json['status'];
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    return {
      'orderId':orderId,
      'userName': userName,
      'totalPrice': totalPrice,
      'shipping': shipping,
      'total': total,
      'phone': phone,
      'address': address,
      'dateTime': dateTime,
      'status': status,
      'productName': productName,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'cardItemList' : cardItemList?.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList()
    };
  }
}
```

and this is update function

```
void updateStatusOfOrdres(String id,{
  required String status,
   int? quantity,
   String? productName,
   String? dateTime,
   String? phone,
   String? address,
   String? orderId,
   String? userName,
   double? totalPrice,
   double? total,
   double? shipping,
   List<dynamic>? cardItemList,
})
  {
    NewOrderModel model = NewOrderModel(
      status: status,
      quantity: quantity,
      productName:productName,
      dateTime: dateTime,
      address:address ,
      orderId: orderId,
      phone:phone ,
      shipping:shipping ,
      total: total,
      totalPrice: totalPrice,
      userName:userName,
      cardItemList:cardItemList ,
    );
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .doc(id)
        .update(model.toMap())
        .then((value) {
      getOrders();
    }).catchError((error){
      emit(UpdateOrdersErrorState(error.toString()));
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
```

and this is the way that called the function into reusable components i send a list of NewOrderModel like that newOrder of index to component and i make this reusable component because i divide  Orders for  three status (new,confirmed,canceled) and each status have a screen and its list

```
AdminCubit.get(context).updateStatusOfOrdres(
              AdminCubit.get(context).ordersNewId[index],
              status: 'canceled',
              userName:model.userName ,
              totalPrice: model.totalPrice,
              total:model.total ,
              shipping:model.shipping ,
              phone: model.phone,
              orderId: model.orderId,
              cardItemList: model.cardItemList,
              address: model.address,
              dateTime:model.dateTime,
              productName: model.productName,
              quantity: model.quantity,
            );
```

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finaly solve this issue by this way

```
void updateStatusOfOrdres(String id,{
  required String status,
   int? quantity,
   String? productName,
   String? dateTime,
   String? phone,
   String? address,
   String? orderId,
   String? orderNumber,
   String? userName,
   double? totalPrice,
   double? total,
   double? shipping,
   String? userEmail,
   List<dynamic>? cardItemList,
})
  {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .doc(id)
        .update({
      'orderId':orderId,
      'userName': userName,
      'totalPrice': totalPrice,
      'shipping': shipping,
      'total': total,
      'phone': phone,
      'address': address,
      'dateTime': dateTime,
      'status': status,
      'productName': productName,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'userEmail': userEmail,
      'orderNumber': orderNumber,
      'cardItemList' : cardItemList?.toList(),
    })
        .then((value) {
      getOrders();
    }).catchError((error){
      emit(UpdateOrdersErrorState(error.toString()));
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).